# 4 (2 X 2) RAM Slot distribution of different vendors

Tags: memory

Currently, I have a single 16 GB Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C40 RAM in my PC. I bought a dual channel 32 GB (2 X 16GB) G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 RAM. Can I use three of my RAM now in the following distribution?

1. SLOT A: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
2. SLOT B: Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C40 - 16GB
3. SLOT C: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB

Is there any performance issue with this configuration? Do I get a full 48GB Performance with these three RAMs?

I also have the plan to increase another Kingston Fury RAM in my 4th slot next month. So the distribution will be then something like

1. SLOT A: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
2. SLOT B: Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C40 - 16GB
3. SLOT C: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
4. SLOT D: Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C40 - 16GB

Again I want to know as previously, is there any performance lagging with this? Do I get full 64GB performance?

Comment: It should work, but the speed is likely to depend on whether your mobo can run triple channel or just dual. I'm not sure that's on topic for here.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I am using Gigabyte Z790 Aorus Elite AX MoBo